# System has orange, blue and white wires but thermostat does not have a place for each

Tags: thermostat, heat-pump

I am trying to update my thermostat so we can set BOTH heat and cool temps. Right now, we get to play the 'go change to heat/cool' game based on what the weather is doing..

**OLD thermostat has (terminal / wire):**

- C = Black
- R = Red
- G = Green
- Y = Yellow
- Aux = Blue
- O/B = Orange
- Aux/W2 = Blue
  [image: OLD THERMOSTAT]

**NEW Thermostat has:**

- C = Black
- R / R/C = Red
- G = Green
- Y = Yellow
- O/B = Orange
- AUX/W2 = Blue

*** There's no place for the W wire.. The W shares a spot with the O/B wire (Orange) and the AUX, the other spot for it, is already occupied with the Blue wire.
[image: NEW THERMOSTAT]

Any suggestions? Do I need to get a different Thermostat??

Comment: Can you post a photo of the wiring at your furnace please?

Comment: I'm not sure where to start on this part.. there's a large unit outside that extends under the house... and the indoor air handler that is in a wall area.. which area should I look for the wiring you need a pic for?

Comment: The indoor air handler is where you'll need to be looking for this wiring

Comment: Hmm. I thought the indoor unit was in a wall area, where the filter is.. but it appears that this unit is actually UNDER the house! I have no clue how to get to the wiring needed for this unit.

Comment: Also, it'd help if you let us know what models these thermostats are...

Comment: The current thermostat is the: Honeywell Home RTH516JRA23118

The new one is the: Honeywell Home RTH7600D

Comment: Hmm i see what you mean,  you get either W or O/B on your new thermostat while the old one had both.  it's possible that one of the wires to your old themostat is not being used. you'll need to check that. eg measure AC voltage from C to W and from C to O/B

Comment: Ok, I was able to test the AC voltage from C to O/B, and C to W, and there is NO AC Voltage between them, or any other C to X wire combo. There is only ~29VAC between C and R, that's it. Thoughts?

Comment: Any further thoughts?

Comment: I recognize that first backplate photo as the plate that comes with the Amazon smart thermostat.

Comment: @Matthew Actually it's a Honeywell thermostat, not an amazon smart thermostat

Answer (score 2):

Without any options or suggestions to make this work, the best option was for me to order a different thermostat, specifically the Honeywell Home RTH8560D 7 Day Programmable Thermostat. This has the same wiring options as the old one.. just took a bit of digging through their installation manuals for several models to find it - they typically don't show the wiring on Amazon or other sites.

Answer (score 0):

The printing of the terminals are off by one. Where it says RC is the W terminal. Honeywell has that problem with the printing of the terminals being off by one with some of their thermostats.

Comment: This could use a citation...